# KeyError exception type Django template tag

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement a template tag into my django project, and I a Key Error. I believe the has to do with getting context in the template tag under load_menu.py.

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:'request'
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\Eric Franzen\PycharmProjects\MySite\templates\app\TikSys\tiksys_home.html, error at line 0

request
1   {% extends 'app/TikSys/tiksysbase.html' %}
2   {% block content %}
3   <div class="body-container">
4   {% include "app/TikSys/sidenavbar.html" %}
5   <div class="col-md-10 ">
6    <div class="jumbotron">
7        <h1>Welcome to TikSys!</h1>
8        <p>Please Sign In</p>
9        </div>
10  </div>
```

Traceback

```
...
File "C:\Users\Eric Franzen\PycharmProjects\MySite\Site\views.py", line 43, in tiksys_home
        return render(request, 'app/TikSys/tiksys_home.html', {})
...
File "C:\Users\Eric Franzen\PycharmProjects\MySite\Site\templatetags\load_menu.py", line 10, in menu
    request = context['request']
```

**Site/templatetags/load_menu.py**

```
from django import template
from Site.models import *

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('app/TikSys/sidenavbar.html', takes_context=True)
def menu(context):
    request = context['request']
    um = UserMunicipal.objects.filter(userID=request.user).values('municipalID')
    m = Municipal.objects.filter(id=um)
    return {'menus': m}
```

**app/TikSys/sidenavbar.html**

```
<div class="col-md-2 NavBar">
    {% load load_menu %}
    {% menu %}
    {% for item in menus %}
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li>{{ item.name }} </li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from Site.forms import UserForm, UserProfileForm
from django.http import *
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Notification, UserMunicipal, Municipal

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def tiksys_home(request):
    return render(request, 'app/TikSys/tiksys_home.html', {})
```

Comment: It is as the error indicates: your context does not have a `request` in it. You might need to add `django.template.context_processors.request` to your context processors setting.

Comment: @solarissmoke my setting.py contains this already,  `'OPTIONS': [ 'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',`

Comment: @solarissmoke I just added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the tag, in the same template that is rendering the tag. This is why there is no context anymore.

The template that the tag renders `app/TikSys/sidenavbar.html`, should only have this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 NavBar">
    {% for item in menus %}
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li>{{ item.name }} </li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

In the main template (where you need the menu), you add - at the top `{% load load_menu %}`, and then where you want the menu, you add `{% menu %}`, like this:

```
{% load load_menu %}
{% extends 'app/TikSys/tiksysbase.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="body-container">
  {% menu %}
  <div class="col-md-10 ">
     <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Welcome to TikSys!</h1>
        <p>Please Sign In</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```